# Python function is not defined

Tags: python, class, oop, python-3.x, jinja2

I face a function undefined error when I run the server (FLASK app):

**NameError: name 'format_date' is not defined**
[image]

This is all my code so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import markdown
import os
from werkzeug import cached_property
import yaml

POSTS_FILE_EXTENSION = '.md'
app = Flask(__name__)

class Post(object):
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path=path
        self._initialize_metadata()

    @cached_property
    def html(self):
        with open(self.path, 'r') as fin:
            content= fin.read().split('\n\n',1)[1].strip()
        return markdown.markdown(content)

    def _initialize_metadata(self):
        content = ''
        with open(self.path, 'r') as fin:
            for line in fin:
                if not line.strip():
                    break
                content +=line
        self.__dict__.update(yaml.load(content))

    def format_date(value, format='%B %d, %Y'):
        return value.strftime(format)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'

@app.route('/blog/<path:path>')
def post(path):
    #import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    path = os.path.join('posts', path+'.md')
    post = Post(path)
    return render_template('post.html', post=post, format_date=format_date)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

Why does it say undefined? I defined it. :|

**post.html:**

```
<h3 id='date'>{{format_date(post.date)}}</h3>
```

**hello.md:**

```
title: Hello, worldtitle!
date: 2013-03-25

# Hello WOrld

### This is an H3 level header
```

P.S. : Don't judge me, I'm a noob.

Comment: What should I import?

Comment: You're missing the actual stacktrace, which probably happens to be on the `render_template` line, because you have the function defined in another file, not the one that contains your `post` function

Comment: Can you show the file structure, and say which file you defined the function in and which one your route is defined in? You need to import the function from the module.

Comment: import the function when rendering the Jinja2 template.... http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/

Comment: Well, `format_date` does not exist. `Post.format_date` exists - as a method defined in class. In Python indentation is **crucial** - it's part of a syntax. Please fix it.

Comment: It's all good with my indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `format_date` function that is defined on the class. You could either define it as a stand alone function, or simply use the method on the Post class. You would need to modify it a bit

```
class Post(object):
    def __init__(self,path):
        ...

    def format_date(self, format='%B %d, %Y'):
        return self.date.strftime(format)
```

And in rendering the template:

```
 return render_template('post.html', post=post)
```

Then you wouldn't need to pass in the function name, and instead just call

```
<h3 id='date'>{{post.format_date()}}</h3>
```

However, this is assuming you have the `date` property defined on your class somewhere (which in your existing template you are assuming you do, but I don't see it anywhere).